# ¿Cómo eliminar valores nulos en una matriz diagonal?

Tags: r, matrices

Tengo un problema, espero puedan ayudarme. Construí una matriz diagonal en la cual tengo valores "0" y quiero eliminarlos ya que solo quiero trabajar con los que tienen datos acumulados.

Esta es la una parte de la matriz diagonal ya que es una matriz mas grande:

```
I<-t(X)%*%X
I
   41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
41  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
42  0  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
43  0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
44  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
45  0  0  0  0  3  0  0  0  0  0
46  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
47  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
48  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  0  0
49  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
50  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2
```

Busqué tutoriales y usé na.omit pero no me funciona porque lo que quiero eliminar son valores nulos (0), también intenté lo siguiente:

```
diag(I)==0
```

para identificar los valores 0, pero luego no sé como eliminar la fila y columna donde están esos valor (en realidad son muchos 0 los que quiero eliminar).

Answer (score 1):

Con la función `diag()`, la cual extrae la diagonal de una matriz, o también construye una matriz diagonal se puede hacer lo que pides. A es tu matriz a la que quieres filtrar los 0 en la diagonal (como en tu ejemplo):

```
A<-diag(c(4,3,2,3,0,0,2,0,2))
A
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
 [1,]    4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    0    3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    2    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    0    3    0    0    0    0    0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    2    0    0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    2
```

Ahora extraemos los valores de la diagonal y filtramos los que son 0`s, y después creamos una nueva matriz con estos valores en la diagonal.

```
A_nueva<-diag(diag(A)[diag(A)!=0])
A_nueva
         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
    [1,]    4    0    0    0    0    0
    [2,]    0    3    0    0    0    0
    [3,]    0    0    2    0    0    0
    [4,]    0    0    0    3    0    0
    [5,]    0    0    0    0    2    0
    [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    2
```

Espero te sirva, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

### Desarrollo

Se puede usar indices para lograr lo que buscas. En este caso no es necesario un bucle `for` ya que las posiciones de las filas y las columnas son las mismas para cualquier posición en la diagonal.

```
dataset <-c(4,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
0,  3,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
0,  0,  2,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
0,  0,  0,  0,  3,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  2,  0,  0,
0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  2)

my_matrix <- matrix(ds, nrow=10, ncol=10)
my_matrix

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [2,]    0    3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [3,]    0    0    2    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [5,]    0    0    0    0    3    0    0    0    0     0
# [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    2    0     0
# [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     2
```

Observa que `my_matrix[4,4]` es cero `0` al igual que `my_matrix[6,6]` `my_matrix[7,7]` y `my_matrix[9,9]`

Como los indices son los mismos para las filas y columnas se puede extraer la diagonal de `my_matrix` y aplicar algo de lógica condicional para filtrar la matriz en cuestion.

```
my_diagonal <- diag(my_matrix)
my_diagonal
# [1] 4 3 2 0 3 0 0 2 0 2

# Nos interesa los valores diferente de cero
index <- my_diagonal!=0
index
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Ya con los indices de tipo "bool" se obtiene la matriz final

```
my_matrix <- my_matrix[index, index]
my_matrix
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    4    0    0    0    0    0
#[2,]    0    3    0    0    0    0
#[3,]    0    0    2    0    0    0
#[4,]    0    0    0    3    0    0
#[5,]    0    0    0    0    2    0
#[6,]    0    0    0    0    0    2
```

### Código resumen

```
my_matrix <- matrix(dataset, nrow=10, ncol=10)
my_diagonal <- diag(my_matrix)
index <- my_diagonal!=0

my_matrix <- my_matrix[index, index]
my_matrix
```